# how to fill value in textbox in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter-3

I have 3 text box and values but I want  to fill values in textbox by jquery.
How I can accomplish this task?

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <input type="text" id="s_nam" name="s_nam" class="form-group" />
</div> 
var s_nam  = $(this).data('slot_name');
$('#s_nam').text(s_nam);
```

Comment: First of `this` refer to the object you are doing something with, like a `click` event. Second I can't see any element with the `data-slot_name`

Comment: try this with either onclick or on submit,

$("#s_nam").text("My TexT");

@CarstenLøvboAndersen sorry, I took a quick look and mistaklen type as the id.thanks

Comment: it that the code as it actually appears in your source code?
If yes, you need to wrap your JS in `<script></script>` tags before doing any debugging ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `data-slot_name` field and you are not accesing the DOM element. You need `$("#s_nam")` in order to access the `input` field:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
 <input type="text" id="s_nam" name="s_nam" data-slote_name="xyz" 
 class="form-group" />
</div> 

var s_nam  = $("#s_nam").data('slot_name');
$('#s_nam').text(s_nam);
```

Second you may encounter an error while trying to grab `s_nam` before the whole page loads so you would need to add:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <input type="text" id="s_nam" name="s_nam" data-slote_name="xyz" 
         class="form-group" />
</div> 

$( document ).ready(function() {

    var s_nam  = $("#s_nam").data('slot_name');
    $('#s_nam').val(s_nam);
});
```

Comment: Oh crap.. Forgot my coffe. Thanks @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score -1):

Hi if you have text box and values you can fill it in multiple ways.

here you can use Id selector( id should be unique in whole page).

but problem is in your code $(this) will refer you current object. and i can't see your any html tag which is having 'slot_name' attribute.

assuming you have input box having attribut name 'slot_name'

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <input type="text" id="s_nam" name="s_nam" class="form-group" slot_name='Slot1' />
</div>
```

you can fetch it by below code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#s_nam").on('blur',function(){
            var s_nam  = $(this).attr('slot_name');
           $(this).val(s_nam);
       })
    });
```

note: you can replace id selector by tag-name to apply it in all input box.

Answer (score -2):

**Set the element using id**

For your example:

```
$('#s_nam').val('Insert the values');
```

```js
$('#s_nam').val('Insert the values');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-4">
 <input type="text" id="s_nam" name="s_nam" 
 class="form-group" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is not really an explanatory answer, It doesn't provide any real information about what the problem is, You say `Set the element using id` but your example show no change regarding this statement.